# Facebook login issue after app activation in production mode - "Function not available" error

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I encountered an issue with the Facebook login functionality in my app. Recently, Facebook restricted my login access, but after providing a user with the TEST role, they activated my app in production mode.

However, now when users attempt to log in to the app, they are presented with the error message: "Function not available: At the moment, the Facebook login is not available because we are updating other application details. Please try again later."

I have already resolved the initial login restriction problem by providing a user with the TEST role. However, this new error persists, and it's impacting user access to the application. I've checked the Facebook developer settings and configurations but haven't found a solution yet.

Could anyone provide insights or steps on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations on potential causes and how to rectify this situation effectively.

My problem :
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/653446630024876/